# TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED in online judge

Tags: c

Today I tried a online coding competition at [CodeChef](http://codechef.com).  When I tried to submit an answer I got "TIME EXCEEDED" warning. The time limit given is 1sec. When I compile it in my pc, it is instantaneous without delay but when I tried compiling the same source code in the websites IDE, it gave me 5sec! How is that possible? What does time limit mean in online competitions?Is it compiling time or time taken from starting of a program to till it's terminated(i.e., compiling+user input+output)?

**Check the question** [here](https://www.codechef.com/COSE2015/problems/CSTRIKE1)

**My code - C**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void sort();
int count = 0,health[500];

int main()
{
int terror,test,i=0,h = 0;
printf("\nTest cases: ");
scanf("%d",&test);
for( h = 1 ; h <= test ; h++)
{
    i=0;
printf("\nTerrorists: ");
scanf("%d",&terror);
while(terror > i)
{
    scanf("%d",&health[i]);
    i++;
    count++;
}
if(i%2 != 0)
{
    printf("\nNO");
}
else
{
    sort();
    int f=0,l=count,v=count,middle = (count/2)+1,j=0,sum1=0,sum2=0;
    for(j=0;j<=middle;j++)
    {
        sum1 += health[f]+health[l];
        f++;l--;
        sum2 += health[j+(middle/2)]+ health[v-(middle/2)];
        v--;
    }
    if (sum1 == sum2)
    {
        printf("\nYES");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNO",);
    }

}
}
return 0 ;
}

void sort()
{
int i , j , a;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    for (j = i + 1; j < count; ++j)
    {
        if (health[i] > health[j])
        {
            a =  health[i];
            health[i] = health[j];
            health[j] = a;
        }
    }
}
}
```

So, can you explain two things

**1**) What does time limit mean in online competitions?Is it compiling time or time taken from starting of a program to till it's terminated(i.e., compiling+user input+output)?

**2**) How can I optimize my code to avoid TLE in the future. Suggest some corrections in the above code.

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding question 1, have you checked the FAQ?

Comment: You need a better sort function. Bubble sort is really slow for large data sets. Try using the qsort function from stdlib

Comment: `if(i%2 != 0){printf("\nNO");}` won't always be `NO`.  Consider this set: `1, 2, 3`.  There is an odd number of terrorists, but `1 + 2 == 3`, so this is `YES`.

Comment: @FiddlingBits oh,thanks! so , how can I check if the the number is odd ? Maximum limit is 500 and checking 499 one by one , there are so many possibilities that time will be exceeded.Any solution?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Thanks!

Comment: @harish One more thing: You should put `\n` at the *end* of each line, not at the beginning. You might be timing out because of a missing newline at the end of your output

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I think thats not a problem because my other answers were accepted.This is the only one  I got rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked two questions:

**1. What does time limit mean in online competitions?**

It is the execution time, not the compilation time. The compilation time is usually insignifcant anyway.

**2. How can I optimize my code to avoid TLE in the future?**

By timing the program yourself, by using `clock()`. If you can't meet the time requirement on your own computer, don't submit an answer. If your computer is slower, you can learn the performance ratio from successful answers, by comparing the result with your own timing.

Here is one way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TIMING 1   // conditional

#if TIMING > 0
#include <time.h>
clock_t start, elap;
#endif

int main()
{
#if TIMING > 0
    start = clock();
#endif

    // solve the problem here
    // mycode...

#if TIMING > 0
    elap = clock() - start;
    printf("Time = %f seconds\n", (double)elap / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I delay input intentionally?Is there a way to provide input before starting the program in terminal?like while typing `./a.out` is there a way to provide then and there all the inputs?

Comment: Why would you be in a time contest and delay intentionally? To tease the judge (a computer program)? The judge will supply input by redirecting from the test case file. You can check same with something like *`myprog <inputs.txt >output.txt`* (Windows console) so you can check the result of known input and output which you have, naturally, already prepared.

Comment: Nitpick.  Prefer `#ifdef TIMING` instead of `#if TIMING > 0`, unless you have variant timing compilations.

Comment: @FiddlingBits FWIW, I have other variants but I agree, the answer is a little slack but I hope that's not enough to put off OP implementing the idea of timing for him/her self.